# JavaScript: Change browser window status message

Tags: javascript, browser

It was once possible to change the message a browser shows in the status bar at the bottom of the window. This functionality has been disabled in newer browser versions due to abuse.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.status = 'hello world';
</script>
```

Is there still any way to achieve this (consider jQuery available)? I think I still see pages around that change the status message, but they might use Flash or Java to change the window status.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things you can do without Flash or Java:

1. Fake it: display a `div` that looks like a status bar.

   ```
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   border: 1px solid silver;
   background: #aaaaaa;
   ```
2. Choose URLs so that you show desired information to the user when they hover over links.

But please don't.

Answer (score 1):

Using the browsers statusbar to display page info is in most cases a very bad idea, the browsers has not disabled it without reason.

1. Nobody looks down there to find such info.
2. People expect it to show *browser* information. When hovering links for example i want to know if i leave the site, if it's a mailto:-link, if it's a pdf etc.

Instead use somthing like the orange(yellow?) thing stackoverflow have at the top of the page. "Are you new to stackoverflow...", "New posts has been added..." etc etc.

Comment: Though this is a related hint it's not an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the pages still changing this info. If it is being done by javascript you should be able to see the source.

Comment: I'd do so, but I didn't bookmark them and can't remember where (or even: if) I have seen them recently.

Comment: I'll keep an eye out and if I see anything I'll report back.

Comment: You are probably not still looking for this, but if you are, here is a page with window status working for browsers that support it: http://www.vic.australis.com.au/hazz/  -  Warning, it's as ugly as you would imagine, haha, and the source code is available.