# Display scrolling message - doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm beginner at JavaScript, and try to do easy core examples accordings this [Workshop: Displaying a Scrolling Message](http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_JavaScript_24_hours&seqNum=61).

But this variant scroll message doesn't work. And I can't understand why this happen. 
My web browser `Google Chrome`, encoding `ANSI`.

**Code:**

```
<html>
    <head><title>Scrolling Message Example</title>
        <script>
            msg = "This is an example of a scrolling message. Isn't it exciting?";
            msg = "...          ..." + msg;
            pos = 0;

            function ScrollMessage() {
               window.status = msg.substring(pos, msg.length) + msg.substring(0, pos);
               pos++;
               if (pos > msg.length) pos = 0;
               window.setTimeout("ScrollMessage()", 200);
            }

            ScrollMessage();
    </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Scrolling Message Example</h1>
            Look at the status line at the bottom of this page. (Don't
            watch it too long, as it may be hypnotic.)
        </body>
</html>
```

**Question:**

- How do solve this trouble?
- Which other variants better to use for this aim?

Comment: Did you tried out: <marquee>text</marquee>

Comment: oh please don't use `marquee`!

Comment: @Lee Taloy why dont use marquee ?

Comment: That tutorial is *way* outdated.  `window.status` isn't supported by any browser anymore.  Also, passing strings to `setTimeout` is bad practice (it uses `eval`); pass functions: `window.setTimeout(ScrollMessage, 200);`

Comment: marquee is clearly deprecated. So you can use [this](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/)

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat I changed to `window.setTimeout(ScrollMessage, 200);` - but this does't change situation.

Comment: Check my answer for a working example Nazar Roskolnikov. I also included the comment of Rocket Hazmat in my answer. Also, in my example I didn't use jquery. You may want to pick up on that too.

Comment: @NazarRoskolnikov: The `setTimeout` wasn't a solution, it's just *better* practice to pass functions, not strings, but both work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

See this post about [JavaScript window.status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273320/javascript-window-status)

Aparently window.status has been disabled by default in most browsers for security reasons.

I assume the exercise is about the scrolling effect, not about the status bar.

If you replace this

```
window.status = msg.substring(pos, msg.length) + msg.substring(0, pos);
```

with

```
console.log(msg.substring(pos, msg.length) + msg.substring(0, pos));
```

You will see in your console that the function that is creating the scroll effect itself is working just fine.

If you want to display the scrolling message, just create a `<div>` in your page where you want to display the message and update the content of the div each time the scroll function is called.

I modified your example:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Scrolling Message Example</title>
        <script>
            var msg = "This is an example of a scrolling message. Isn't it exciting?";
            msg = "...          ..." + msg;
            var pos = 0;

            function ScrollMessage() {
                document.getElementById("scrollMsgContainer").innerHTML = msg.substring(pos, msg.length) + msg.substring(0, pos);
                pos++;
                if (pos > msg.length) pos = 0;
                window.setTimeout(ScrollMessage, 200);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Scrolling Message Example</h1>
        Look at the status line at the bottom of this page. (Don't
        watch it too long, as it may be hypnotic.)

        <div id="scrollMsgContainer" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; background-color: #DDDDDD">&nbsp;</div>
    </body>
    <script>
        ScrollMessage();
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat I did this replace `console.log(msg.substring(pos, msg.length) + msg.substring(0, pos));` - and msg is displaing into console. But I don't understand last of answer about `<div>`. Can you show code for circumvent this issue?

Comment: You should really add `var` before `msg` and `pos` (wow, that tutorial really needs to be updated).

Comment: @Nazar, I believe the important part about the (albeit outdated) tutorial is not about the status bar, but about exercising. The `div` is indeed an area in the page. It is only used to display the scrolling text. I used it to replace the status bar.

Comment: @Iljaas How do change window.status at the correct way into Google Grome?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `document.title` instead:

```
function ScrollMessage() {
               document.title = msg.substring(pos, msg.length) + msg.substring(0, pos);
               pos++;
               if (pos > msg.length) pos = 0;
               window.setTimeout("ScrollMessage()", 200);
            }
```

It's supported in all browsers except for IE <= 7;

Answer (score 0):

Check [MDN window.status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.status) reference.
Google Chrome have not status bar and Mozilla Firefox blocks status bar changes by default.

You could try a [Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) in HTML and set the content of it.

Hope it help..

Comment: How do change this into chrom? Which points schould be change?