# Display content of browser status bar in webpage

Tags: php, javascript, html

Can we display the content of Browser's status bar in our Web Page ? Like when I am uploading a file it shows status like "Sending Request" then "Uploading 5%" and so on. Can we directly show this in web page ?

Comment: you sure can my man! if this was the best answer provided be sure to mark it as the right answer :)

Comment: You're too late. [It's not possible for over three years now](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3273320/447356). Browsers won't allow you to read or write the status..

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can do it by

`window.status`

command in javascript.

**Note:**  The status property does not work in the default configuration of IE, Firefox, Chrome, or Safari. To allow scripts to change the text of the status, the user must set the dom.disable_window_status_change preference to false in the about:config screen. (or in Firefox: "Tools - Options - Content -Enable JavaScript / Advanced - Allow scripts to change status bar text").

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is:

```
window.status
```

... in javascript. But apparently most browsers don't support this.

Do something like:

```
var element = document.getElementById('someelement');
setInterval(function() {
    element.innerHTML = window.status;
}, 50);
```

When you upload a file, then clear the interval when you're done.