# how to hide url address in status bar?

Tags: javascript, url, browser, statusbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: Change browser window status message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536691/javascript-change-browser-window-status-message)

When we hover on some link text, the target link is shown in the status bar. How can we hide the link address in the status bar. For example, in following link:

```
<a href="javascript:$('#fileUpload2').fileUploadStart()">Start Upload</a>
```

Comment: You're solving the wrong problem — which is that you are using a link in the first place. If you use a regular submit button and then progressively enhance it to do a background upload (assuming that is what the JS does) then your problem goes away. (Not that the status bar giving status information to the user should be a problem in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a onClick="javascript:$('#fileUpload2').fileUploadStart()" href="javascript:void(0)">Start Upload</a>`
```

Only `javascript:void(0)` will show up in the browser window.

James

Comment: Still a bad practice: don't use an anchor element when you're not providing a hyperlink. See David's comment on the question.

Comment: @Marcel: I agree it's not a good way of doing things, but it works. David's comment is a much better way of doing this. Thanks.