# Is it possible to show url hint in bottom left on hover

Tags: javascript

I've got a datagrid with rows, and on row click I redirect the user to a new page. Since I'm not using an anchor `<a>` tag, I would like to display the URL preview/hint at the bottom left on row hover as if it were an actual link element. See attached picture below:

Assuming my element to hover is:

```
<div class="data-row">...</div>
```

On hover I want to see:

```
localhost:3000/at/accounts
```

[image]

Is this possible with JS or some other mechanism?

Comment: so make it an anchor tag? `<a class="data-row" href=''>`

Comment: Is there a reason it has to be a div instead of just a anchor tag?

Comment: @epascarello sorry, I failed to mention (I probably should have) that I'm using MUI's datagrid and I don't have control over the markup it renders for each row. I can only change a cell. So the markup I get for each row is a div. What are my options still, if any?

Comment: @JasonAyer have u managed to find a solution to this?

Comment: @PCPbiscuit I have not yet

Comment: Once upon a time there was a little property that could, which lived on `window` and was called `status`. For good reason, it had been/was being euthanized by 2009. See [`Window.status` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status), https://stackoverflow.com/q/536691/15261914, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3273330/15261914.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes thanks for that info. I have set my question to be closed as a duplicate of one of those links you provided, the one that has an accepted solution.